# About Kernel normalization in regression

Tags: regression, gaussian-process, kernel-trick

Is it a good idea to normalize your kernel in the Gaussian Process Regression framework?
By normalization, I mean $K_{norm}(x,y) = \frac{K(x,y)}{\sqrt{K(x,x)\times K(y,y)}}$.

For instance, take a polynomial kernel $K(x,y) = (<x,y>+b)^{d}$, where $d >0$. Thus, the "standard" polynomial kernel is not normalized. Is there any advantage of normalizing it?

Comment: +1, yes you have come across a real problem. Please see my answer below for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct to note that certain kernels (polynomial being the prime example) suffect from numerical instability. This is pronounced as if $\langle x,y\rangle +b < 0$ then $(\langle x,y\rangle+b)^d \rightarrow 0$ as $d$ increases and vice versa if $\langle x,y\rangle +b > 0$ then $(\langle x,y\rangle+b)^d \rightarrow \infty$ as $d$ increases.

In general, it is more relevant to try to normalise the inputs $x$ and $y$ beforehand. For example, in `R` the code `poly` creates by default orthogonal polynomial to directly account for the inherit numerical stability of raising small or large number to increases powers. As we can cannot directly do that for a GPR the next best thing is to normalise our input.
To that extent and quoting directly from the Rasmussen & Williams (2007), [Gaussian Processes for Machine Learning, Chapt. 4](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW4.pdf):
*"For regression problems the polynomial kernel is a rather strange choice as the prior variance grows rapidly with $|x|$ for $|x|>1$. However, such kernels have proved effective in high-dimensional classification problems (e.g. take to be a vectorized binary image) where the input data are binary or grey scale normalized to [−1,1] on each dimension [Schoelkopf and Smola, 2002, sec. 7.8]"*.

So to bring everything together: Focus normalising the inputs rather than the kernel (or use a kernel that allows accounting for the scale of the inputs used (e.g. Matérn, RBF, etc.)).

Comment: It was exactly the type of answer I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Cool, I am glad I could help! :)